# increase shared element transition speed

Tags: java, android, shared-element-transition

I have implemented shared element image transition with recycler view and its working fine. The issue is that i want to increase its image transition speed like google photo app have. Can we do this programmetically ? I'm sharing few lines of code.

**Start Activity**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_IMAGES_URLS, urls);
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                        makeSceneTransitionAnimation(StartActivity.this, view,
getResources().getString(R.string.transition_name_profile_image));
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(StartActivity.this, intent, options.toBundle());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change the transition time in your activity as:

```
    getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(new ChangeBounds().setDuration(2000));
```

Comment: if the data is from internet, should i wait the data is download?

Comment: It is up to you, You can show a `ProgressDialog` until data is fetched then make the transition. Or you can start the `Activity` and show a `ProgressDialog` until data is fetched.

Comment: But, the `ProgressDialog` is not a good idea when you use SharedElementTransition

Comment: i am not getting the scenario you are trying to implement. please elaborate.